# Android TCP Client / Server Crashes

Tags: android, tcp, crash

Hello I'm very new to TCP and I want to build a multiplayer game. But I'm encountering a fatal error that crashes my application everytime I open the 'Client.java' class.

I get a android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException, I've added the INTERNET permission in android manufest. I go to this class from another using Intent and yes I have setOnClickListener(this); there and added Activity to the manufest so it doesn't crash because of that. 
And If this is a good idea, im building the TCP server and client both within the application, then how am I going to make it a public host? Like I need to pay for a host and then use the ip/port in the server and client?

Anyway here's the code:

```
package com.theory.game;
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.InputStreamReader; 
import java.io.PrintWriter; 
import java.net.Socket; 
import java.util.Scanner; 
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.widget.EditText; 
import android.widget.TextView; 

public class Client extends Activity { 
/** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
//StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); 


@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.client); 
    //StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);  
    final EditText msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMsg); 
    Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend); 
    final TextView convo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvConvo); 
    final TextView status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStatus); 

    try { 
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

            Socket s = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 8080); 
            String message = msg.getText().toString(); 

            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                status.setText("..."); 
                PrintWriter outp = null; 
                BufferedReader inp = null; 
                status.setText("Established connection.."); 
                String serverMsg = null; 

                try { 
                    outp = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true); 
                    inp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream())); 
                    serverMsg = inp.readLine(); 
                } catch (IOException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 
                convo.append(serverMsg + "\n"); 

                if (message != null) { 
                    if (msg.getText().toString().trim() == "QUIT") { 
                        try { 
                            s.close(); 
                        } catch (IOException e) { 
                            e.printStackTrace(); 
                        } 
                        status.setText("Disconnected from server."); 

                    } else { 
                            try { 

                                convo.append(message + "\n"); 
                                outp.println(message);  
                                serverMsg = inp.readLine(); 
                                convo.append(serverMsg + "\n"); 
                            } catch (IOException e) { 
                                e.printStackTrace(); 
                            } 
                    } 

                } 
                else 
                    status.setText("Problem in connection..!"); 
            } 
        }); 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
} 
}


`FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-13 22:53:18.542: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)

E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(706): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)

E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:127)
E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:177)
E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:149)
E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at com.theory.game.Client$1.<init>(Client.java:35)
E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at com.theory.game.Client.onCreate(Client.java:33)
E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)

E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)

E/AndroidRuntime(706):  ... 11 more `
```

Comment: Can you post the call trace from log cat.

Comment: Yes TJ I've modified my post, please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you targeting SDK 11 or higher and have strict mode on? NetworkOnMainThreadException is thrown whenever you try to do a network operation on the main thread. Move your network code to an AsyncTask instead. Not only will you take care of the exception but you'll also improve your application.

Using AsyncTask's are super easy and there's lots of good tutorials for them. [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and tutorial by [Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html).